# using interface to communicate between 2 java classes

Tags: java, interface, scope, class-method, class-members

I have 2 classes A and B.

`class A implements Constants{`

```
   private int state;
```

}

```
class B implements Constants{
foo(){
   //want to set state variable of class A like this
   state = state1
 }

}
interface Constants{
 public final int state1;
 public final int state2;
}
```

I don't want to have an instance of class A in class B. How should I do this? 
If I have a function to set the variable in the interface, then both the classes must implement this function. That would be wrong right? Because then 2 definitions for the same function would conflict?

Comment: Question is unclear. Do you want that B extends A?

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing called functions in java. They are methods.

You can have getters and setters in your classes for the properties to set and get them from external classes.

Your question is unclear.

If your B class extends the A class, then through the constructor of the B class, you can set the properties of the A class that is the super class.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Having an interface does not mean that the variable will be shared between the classes, it is more of a way to define classes that MUST override the functions in the interface. You can read the very basics on them [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/interface.html). To share a variable between two classes, you can either make the variable static and put it in another class that both your classes extend (in effect a global variable, which is bad practice and not thread safe), or have one of the classes have an instance of the other and call getters/setters.

EDIT: there is a similar question [here](http://www.java-forums.org/new-java/49364-abstract-class-one-static-variable.html) that shows you what I mean about the static variable.

Answer (score 0):

You generally want to avoid writing any method in a class that attempts to alter the internal state of another class. Whatever trick you come up with to accomplish such a thing, you are breaking the principle of encapsulation which is the whole reason for using classes in the first place.

If there is some state that you wish to have accessible from multiple classes, I would recommend breaking that state out into it's own class and have each of the two classes interact with it through getter/setter or utility methods.